# Exponential Function Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, arm, exponential

I'm trying to debug the assembly language code that takes the 2 integer: x and y and put it through the function x^y. But it seems to have problem when I put in the y value beyond 2. When I put in X =3, Y = 3 example, the results I got is 9 which is incorrect (3^3 = 27)

I'm using a Keli uVision 5, with NXP LPC2833 Development board

I'm new to this community. So, sorry to all the advanced programmers if I made a rookie mistakes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEi6S.png

```
     AREA EXPONENT, CODE, READONLY
     ENTRY
start
     MOV a1, #3     ; X value
     MOV a2, #3     ; Y value
     BL X_POWER_Y   ; Go to X_POWER_Y function
B loop

X_POWER_Y

  CMP a2, #0        ;Checks if Y equals 0
  BEQ ZERO_COND

  CMP a2,#1         ;Checks if Y equals 1
  BEQ POWER_1

  MOV a3, a2
  MOV v1, a1

  while CMP a3, a2 
        BLT BREAK

        SUB a3, a3, #1
        MUL a4, a1, v1
        MOV v1, a4

        B while

POWER_1
   MOV a4, a1
   B BREAK

ZERO_COND
   MOV a4, #1
   B BREAK

BREAK
   MOV a1, a4

loop B loop
   END
```

Comment: `CMP a3, a2`/ `BLT BREAK` <-- That looks like it would exit the loop as soon as you reach the second iteration. What were you really attempting to do?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was trying other formats of code before. I must have forgotten to rewrite that section.

Comment: Update: I have changed that section of the code to   
         `MOV a3, #0`/`MOV v1, a1`/`while CMP a3, a2`/`BGT BREAK`/`ADD a3, a3, #1`

Have tried re-run the code again, now the results is 0x000000F3, still not correct.

Comment: It should probably be `MOV a3,#1` and `BGE BREAK`. And of course the `SUB` inside the loops needs to be an `ADD`.

Comment: Wow. I tried changing that to your suggested value, run a few number tests. Everything seems to be working as expected. Thanks! I'll be more careful checking my code. @Michael

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your issue. You have to run loop for y - 1 time so I have initialized a2 with one and it will run until a2 becomes equal to or greater than y (3 in your case)

```
     AREA EXPONENT, CODE, READONLY
     ENTRY
start
     MOV a1, #3     ; X value
     MOV a2, #3     ; Y value
     BL X_POWER_Y   ; Go to X_POWER_Y function
B loop

X_POWER_Y

  CMP a2, #0        ;Checks if Y equals 0
  BEQ ZERO_COND

  CMP a2,#1         ;Checks if Y equals 1
  BEQ POWER_1
```

> ```
>   MOV a3, #1
> ```

```
  MOV v1, a1

while 
        CMP a3, a2
```

> ```
>         BGE BREAK
> ```

```
        ADD a3, a3, #1
        MUL a4, a1, v1
        MOV v1, a4

        B while

POWER_1
   MOV a4, a1
   B BREAK

ZERO_COND
   MOV a4, #1
   B BREAK

BREAK
   MOV a1, a4

loop B loop
   END
```